# How can I save a xml file got via curl?

Tags: php, xml, curl

I have this proxy done using curl. I t successfully gets the xml to be displayed in the page. I'm trying to save a copy locally with no success, i tried (already in the complete code below):

```
$fp = fopen('data.xml', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $xml);
fclose($fp);
```

But I got no error and an empty "data.xml" file...How can this be done?
thanks

[EDIT2]: solved, i just added the flag: `curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`
and done! (updated in the code below
The code with @spell suggestion.

```
define ('HOSTNAME', 'http://www.camara.gov.br');


$path = "http://www.camara.gov.br/SitCamaraWS/Deputados.asmx/ObterDeputados?";
$url = HOSTNAME.$path;

$session = curl_init($path);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36');

header("Content-Type: text/xml");


$xml = curl_exec($session);


curl_close($session);

file_put_contents ('./data.xml', $xml); 
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `file_put_contents` function.

In your case it will be:

```
// Make the call
$xml = curl_exec($session);


// done, shutDown.
curl_close($session);

if (file_put_contents ('./data.xml', $xml) !== false) {
     echo 'Success!';
} else {
     echo 'Failed';
}
```

And

> But I got no error and an empty "data.xml" file

Next time provide an error

Comment: Hi @Spell, thanks for your help. It almost did it, but I still getting an empty file after all... I edited the question with the code that I'm running now, with a link to it too. Also If I leave the echo on, it seems to append the string to end of the xml causing an error, so i stripped it for now. Could you have a look at this again please? Thanks

Comment: It was missing `curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` code edited above. solved. thanks