# Import XML products to Prestashop in PHP

Tags: php, xml, prestashop

I need create a PHP file to import a lot of products from a external source (a distributor) to my Prestashop 1.7.6.

I need to connect with this service "http://www.ferrunion.com/ita/codice/id_service.php" to take the token and when I recive this string I need to connect with this service "http://www.ferrunion.com/ita/codice/catalogo_service.php" to recive the XML file.

This is an example of the structure of the XML:

```
<![CDATA[ 
   <product>  
      <id>id<id>
      <description>description</description>
      <quantity>quantity</quantity>
      <confezione>confezione</confezione>
      <prezzo_lordo>prezzo acquisto senza sconti</prezzo_acquisto>
      <price>price</price>
      <info>info</info>
   </product> 
]]>
```

The problema are 2:

- How can I conncet whit this services in PHP language?
- When I have the file, how can import the XML code in my Prestashop's database?

---

Can you help me with this problem?

Thanks you.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Both of those questions (which should rather be asked separately to begin with), are overly broad. This is not a tutorial site to answer “how to do X” questions - you need to put in a bit more effort yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your idea is to develop a Prestashop module and run it using a cron, is that so?

Have you tried to bring the XML file using curl?

From your Prestashop module you must bring the XML via CURL. Once you have the XML loaded you just have to parse (take a look:https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_dom.asp) the file and process each product with the Prestashop API.

Tell me if I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

### First create a module

Use module generator to speed up the process
Generate starting module online at https://validator.prestashop.com/generator

### 1 Download th file

Use curl to download the file to your serwer

See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248371/how-can-i-save-a-xml-file-got-via-curl

### 2 Proces the file and insert/update products: 
2.1) Through SQL directly to DB
2.2) Through PrestaShop API or
2.3) Through internal Product Class object (reccomended)

2.1 Create PHP script to load xml and run some customs SQL insert directly (you will need to handle images upload and insert all images to db which is not that trivial). So you would need to populate some or all of this tables:

- ps_product
- ps_product_lang
- ps_product_shop
- ps_stock_available
- ps_category_product
- ps_image
- ps_product_download
  ...

2.2 Use PrestaShop API which will take a resource through URL endpoint and insert it to database internally. This way PrestaShop system will take care of a lot of thing for you, and you will not have to update your script with every new PrestaShop release if they decide to change something in database (or take care of uploading your images and database relations)

2.3 Use Prestashop internal Product class to insert new product wo database.

```
<?php 
  // add category first then make reference to category

  // configure and add product
  $product = new Product;
  $product->name = $productName;
  $product->ean13 = '';
  $product->reference = '';
  $product->id_category_default = $getCategoryID;
  $product->category = $getCategoryID;
  $product->indexed = 1;
  $product->description = $description;
  $product->condition = 'new';
  $product->redirect_type = '404';
  $product->visibility = 'both';
  $product->id_supplier = 1;
  $product->link_rewrite = $link_rewrite;
  $product->quantity = $singleStock;
  $product->price = round($price - (18.69 / 100) * $price, 2);
  $product->active = 1;
  $product->add();
```

Prestahop import script example [here](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/878717-how-to-add-image-to-product-object-in-prestashop-17/)
Investigate Product Class [here](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.7.7.x/classes/Product.php)

#### Working with large XML files

When running php on large XML file do not load all the file to memory with simplexml_load_file() function. Instead use XMLReader combined with SimpleXMLElement.

```
<?php

// this is not PrestaShop related script. This is pure PHP for manipulating large XML files.

// first load the file with curl and save it on your server in desired location. Then load the file as in example below:

$continueFrom = getLastNumWhereItStoped();

$iCount = 0;
$limit = 1000;
 
$xml = new XMLReader();

/*
* One-liners to gzip and ungzip a file:
* copy('file.txt', 'compress.zlib://' . 'file.txt.gz');
* copy('compress.zlib://' . 'file.txt.gz', 'file.txt');
*/
$xml->open('compress.zlib://'.'filename.xml.gz');
 
while($xml->read() && $xml->name != 'product')
{
  // skip all not important nodes and stop on "product" node
}

/**
 * Run on every "product" node untill it hits 1000
 */
while($xml->name == 'product' && $limit + $continueFrom >= $iCount)
{

  if($iCount <= $continueFrom ) continue;

  $element = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->readOuterXML());
  
  $product = array(
    'name' => strval($element->text->name),
    'price' => strval($element->price->buynow),
    'parent_category' => strval($element->category->attributes()->parent_category) // category have to be created before product import [maping category is as easy as you might think]
  );
  
  // ... do something with $product set create Product Class instance or... send it to API or make SQL insert directly 

  // if product exists just update the product value you want (for example price and stock quantity).
 
  $iCount++;
  
  $xml->next('product');
  unset($element);
}
```

/* If success */
$continueFrom = setLastNumWhereItStoped($continueFrom + $limit);

### 3 Schedule the task

Set CRON job tu run the script automatically (download XML) then run update on fields you really need to update. Read your host provider docs on how to do that

### DOCS PrestaShop API endpoint

#### Generate access token

Enable the webservice By default, the webservice feature is disabled on PrestaShop and needs to be switched on before the first use. You can enable it using GUI or programmatically. Both method are presented here:

https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/webservice/tutorials/creating-access/

#### Create a resource

vTo create a resource, you simply need to GET the XML blank data for the resource (example /api/someendpoint?schema=blank), fill it with your changes, and send POST HTTP request with the whole XML as body content to the /api/someendpoint/ URL.

PrestaShop will take care of adding everything in the database, and will return an XML file indicating that the operation has been successful, along with the ID of the newly created customer.

#### Update a resource

To edit an existing resource: GET the full XML file for the resource you want to change (example /api/someendpoint/1), edit its content as needed, then send a PUT HTTP request with the whole XML file as a body content to the same URL again.

#### Usefull resources:

https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/webservice/
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/webservice/getting-started
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/creation/external-services/
https://drib.tech/programming/parse-large-xml-files-php

Use DB:
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/database/db/
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/database/structure/

How are images stored - path generation explained
[Insert image to prestashop database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34792567/insert-image-to-prestashop-database)

The topic is quite broad but hope that this will get you started.